# install PHP DOM extension on shared hosting via PHP itself or a cron job on CPanel

Tags: cron, installation, shared-hosting, php-extension

I need to install the [PHP DOM extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) on my server, however I'm using a free shared hosting host for this project, and I have *no command line access, (but I can FTP/upload files, if that helps)*. Could this be done by using:

1. a PHP file itself to download and install when I run the script? I was able to make a symbolic link from inside a php file before. I was wondering if I could do the same for setting-up PHP DOM... or
2. by setting-up a cron job on cPanel to do this?

and how? Sorry for such a noob question, I haven't been that lucky with searches. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. I didn't test it but you can try the function dl(); http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php.
2. Why would a cron job can help you to load  a dll? That's not how it works.

Comment: 1. aaiyt, will check that out, and 2. good to know, thanks much @Chibox